# Report deployment status to Boards not working

Tags: azure-devops, deployment, continuous-deployment

I've been banging my head trying to figure out why Report deployment status to Boards isn't working. I have followed the documentation to the "T" but it still doesn't work. Any help would be appricietaed. Here is my setup:

Azure DevOps Service

**Version Dev19.M233.1 (AzureDevOps_M233_20240114.1)**

**Pipeline is configured with:**
[image]

**Release is configured as:**
[image]

When I run a test by creating a commit and assigning it to the work item, I see the commit and build get added to the work item but when release succeeds, the Development section never updates and still shows the default verbiage:
[image]
[image]

I'm not sure what else to look for. I can see the link type is available. I am completely lost on this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you may test to check `Report deployment status to Work` option, which creates links to all work items linked to associated changes when the stage completes.
[image]

Enabling `Report deployment status to Boards` doesn't populate the `Integrated in release stage` link, while enabling `Report deployment status to Work` does.
[image]

Comment: I'll try this out and report back.

Comment: I tried this but the `Integrated in release stage` link still is not populating...
I can see the `Integrated in build` link but not the `Integrated in release stage`

Comment: Has the release pipeline `CD` consumed the artifacts published by the `CI` pipeline that is triggered by a commit associated with a work item? Perhaps, you may generate new CI&CD pipelines with simple tasks to publish and download artifacts to test this feature.

Comment: Yes, we tested that. We have submitted a support ticket with MS as this seems to be an internal bug. I will post the results once resolved.